# Decomposing U.S. Imports of Goods by Customs Basis from China

Tags: time-series, modeling, econometrics, stationarity, seasonality

I'm working on a project which aims at analyzing the dataset [U.S. Imports of Goods by Customs Basis from China (IMPCH)](https://fred.stlouisfed.org/series/IMPCH). The main point is to make some prediction but we also want to do a little inference from the data.

As far as I know, the first step is to decompose the time series. There are at least five decomposition methods and the residual (remainder) of all of them passes the unit root tests, indicating the results are stationary, which is desired. However, now I have to pick one of them to proceed, but all seem good.

Which one should I choose, `decompose`, `HoltWinters`, `forecast::ets`, `stl`, or `seasonal::seas`?

```
# dataset
# https://fred.stlouisfed.org/series/IMPCH

IMPCH <- read.csv("IMPCH.csv")
imp <- IMPCH$IMPCH
imp.ts <- ts(imp, frequency = 12, start = 1985)
log.imp.ts <- log(imp.ts)
ts.plot(log.imp.ts)
```

[image]

```
## Decomposition
library(tseries)

# Stock decompose
log.imp.ts.dcps <- decompose(log.imp.ts)
plot(log.imp.ts.dcps)
log.imp.ts.dcps.remainder <- na.remove(log.imp.ts.dcps$random)
adf.test(log.imp.ts.dcps.remainder)
pp.test(log.imp.ts.dcps.remainder)
kpss.test(log.imp.ts.dcps.remainder)
```

[image]

```
# Holt-Winters Filtering
log.imp.ts.hw <- HoltWinters(log.imp.ts)
plot(log.imp.ts.hw)
log.imp.ts.hw.remainder <- resid(log.imp.ts.hw)
adf.test(log.imp.ts.hw.remainder)
pp.test(log.imp.ts.hw.remainder)
kpss.test(log.imp.ts.hw.remainder)
```

[image]

```
# ETS
library(forecast)
log.imp.ts.ets <- ets(log.imp.ts)
plot(log.imp.ts.ets)
log.imp.ts.ets.remainder <- resid(log.imp.ts.ets)
adf.test(log.imp.ts.ets.remainder)
pp.test(log.imp.ts.ets.remainder)
kpss.test(log.imp.ts.ets.remainder)
```

[image]

```
# STL
log.imp.ts.stl <- stl(log.imp.ts, s.window = "periodic", robust = TRUE)
plot(log.imp.ts.stl)
log.imp.ts.stl.remainder <- log.imp.ts.stl$time.series[, "remainder"]
adf.test(log.imp.ts.stl.remainder)
pp.test(log.imp.ts.stl.remainder)
kpss.test(log.imp.ts.stl.remainder)
```

[image]

```
# X-13ARIMA-SEATS
library(seasonal)
log.imp.ts.seas <- seas(log.imp.ts)
plot(log.imp.ts.seas)
log.imp.ts.seas.remainder <- resid(log.imp.ts.seas)
adf.test(log.imp.ts.seas.remainder)
pp.test(log.imp.ts.seas.remainder)
kpss.test(log.imp.ts.seas.remainder)
```

[image]

Comment: have you seen the answer and/or managed to make any progress with the problem in question?

Answer (score 3):

Holt-Winters is not telling us a lot about the data in terms of additive decomposition, it's only really doing some smoothing. I definitely wouldn't go with that.

Next, ETS. It's better than HW, but it's not segregating the random component of the data. Looking at your results, it seems to be distributing the random variability between the slope and the season components as opposed to isolating it. Also, I don't feel the slope is really telling us much here, it's a bit redundant when you have the level. So, I wouldn't use ETS.

The tseries results look clean and the components are what I would expect. Much better than the previous 2.

STL: personally, I would go with STL. The results you got are more or less as clean as the decompose ones, but I prefer STL because it uses local regression, is robust to outliers, and lets you control the smoothness of the trend cycle.